# home page modules shows in all the inner pages in opencart

Tags: opencart

i have opencart 1.5.6 installed with Oxy theme, i have set a slide show, featured, latest and a custom block module to show only on the home page (home layout) and position top which works great.. but when i go to the inner pages it shows in all the inner pages on top

in the layout, its set to the correct path

```
common/home
```

but still it shows in all the inner pages. can someone tell me what might be causing this? how can i show only in my home page?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect if you go to System->settings->edit->store, "Home" will be set up as the default layout. If so, change it to something else. Ideally, create a "Default" layout for this purpose (with no routes)

What's set as the default layout will be used by ALL pages, except any that match a route in any other layout.